# Como extraes números (decimales de 1 o 2 ) de una cadena de texo?

Tags: sql

Por favor su apoyo. Tengo ejemplo las cadenas de texto

```
Plan Habla S/ 45 C
Plan Elige m-ás S/ 109.90
```

Modalidad Corporativa

```
Plan Elige Todo S/ 69
```

y deseo obtener:

```
45 109.90 0 69
```

como realizaría la consulta en SQL?

Comment: Que gestor? Que llevas hecho? Por favor considera leer  [ask]

Comment: Te dejo el link con la solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas SQL Server, puedes usar STRING_SPLIT, ISNUMERIC y COALESCE de esta forma:

```
DECLARE @partes NVARCHAR(400) = 'Plan Habla S/ 45 C Plan Elige m-ás S/ 109.90 Plan Elige Todo S/ 69'  
DECLARE @resultado VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @resultado = COALESCE(@resultado + ' ', '') + value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@partes, ' ')  
WHERE ISNUMERIC(value) <> 0

print @resultado
```

Y te devuelve:

```
45 109.90 69
```

Suerte!

Comment: siempre y cuando sea sqlserver, no?

Comment: Si, pensé que estabas utilizando SQL Server.  ¿Qué motor estás usando?

Comment: Eso se lo preguntaron a quien hizo la pregunta en un comentario

Comment: Además de que debe ser en la versión 2016 o posterior.